# Library or program to make TWAIN-compatible scanner send documents to a J2EE application

Tags: scanning

I am building software which requires scanning a document directly from a TWAIN-compatible scanner and saving it. After searching for few days, I have been unable to find a good (cheap, workable) option for implementing this. I want to integrate scanning functionality directly inside my J2EE software rather than using some external API (for which the user needs to go outside the software).

Simply put: How to make the scanner talk to the J2EE application so that when the user presses 'Scan' button in the application the scanner starts and scans the document and saves it through the application.

What software (library) can I use for that?

Comment: I have voted to reopen your question and edited it **because you still were not asking for software** after your edit. Write good questions, please.